# Why can't I see the results from mongodb on my created page?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am building a recipe website for my project ( am rookie coder ) and I can't fetch data from my mongodb database. I have created a page add_recipes works fine and posts everything to database. I want these recipes that have been posted in the database to show on a page called Recipes. If anyone could help me out that would be awesome!
Here is my code:
Python.

```py
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/get_recipes")
def get_recipes():
    recipes = list(mongo.db.recipes.find())
    return render_template("recipes.html", recipes=recipes)
```

Here is html with jinja:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for recipe in recipes %}
        {{ recipe.title }}<br>
        {{ recipe.description }}<br>
        {{ recipe.ingredients }}<br>
        {{ recipe.image }}<br>
        {{recipe.created_by}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: My guess is the problem lies in `recipes = list(mongo.db.recipes.find())`. Can you verify make sure that line of code is returning valid data?

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Yes you are right i checked and it was not returning data :)